# Python: How to allow user to select line to edit?

Tags: python

I've been trying to load a text file into Python and replace the last word. The text file looks like this:

```
A1 I'm at the shop with Bill
B3 I'm going to the shop with Sarah
E3 I was at the shop with nobody
F5 I'm at the shop with Cameron
```

I'd like to allow the user to choose which line to edit. So, they could enter B3 for the second line and then replace the name at the end. I've tried numerous things with it as a function, but I just can't number the lines to be edited.

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: They were all centred around trying to loop through the text file and if the phrase entered by the user was matched, it would select that line. I tried enumerate a few times but wasn't getting any results.

Comment: Can you update your post with the code and the expected behaviour? There are several ways to do what you want. The index letter does not follow any pattern? How do you plan to retrieve the line?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ord(c)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) function to convert a letter into a number, and use that to choose your line index.

```
choice = input("Enter the row you would like to change")

if choice.isalpha(): # if they enter 1 or b or C
    choice_num = ord(choice.lower()) - 97
else:
    choice_num = choice

with open('shops.txt') as shoplist:
    lines = shoplist.read().splitlines()
    name = lines[choice_num].split()[-1]
    lines[choice_num] = lines[2].replace(name, "Steve")
    with open ('shops.txt','w') as shoplist:
        for l in lines:
            shoplist.write(l+"\n')
```

Comment: Sorry, I've realised that I wrote out the text file incorrectly. I've fixed it now. The initial letter doesn't really follow a pattern.